# Delete dynamic table in modal popup on modal close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

On button click a modal popup will open where table rows are appended to the table in following way

```
   var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
   var newCell1 = document.createElement("td");

  newCell1.innerHTML = rowValue;

  newRow.append(newCell1);
  document.getElementById("tablerows").appendChild(newRow);
```

tablerows is the id of table tbody so the rows get appended to the table in modal popup. Now on modal close I want to clear the table. I have tried this

```
      $("#formID")[0].reset()
      $("#tableId tbody tr").remove()
```

This works only for fields inputs in the popup. What is the way to clear the dynamic table on modal close

Answer (score 0):

Put a class in your dynamic rows.

```
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
var newCell1 = document.createElement("td");
newRow.classList.add("dynamic-row")
newCell1.innerHTML = rowValue;

newRow.append(newCell1);
document.getElementById("tablerows").appendChild(newRow);
```

And remove them

```
$("#formID")[0].reset()
$('#tableId tbody .dynamic-row').remove()
```